# How to attach to WordPress ContactForm 7 email custom file

Tags: php, wordpress, email-attachments

I have from my PM this task. We have a table of products specs. The last column contains buttons to download product catalog. User click button and should get a popup with ContactForm 7 form. When user submit form one letter with user info should be sent to manager. And second letter should be sent to user. It should have attached catalog PDF-file depending of which button user clicked. Button in Product 1 row - Product 1 catalog, button in Product 2 row - Product 2 catalog...
First I tried to create hidden file field and change it value via JS depending of clicked button. But browsers don't allow to do it simply.
So I decided to form custom email data and send it via custom mailer script. I have following HTML:

```
...
<td>Prod 1</td>
<td>G.3/8</td>
<td><a class="lsb-38 button-catalogo" href="#">Download</a></td>
<td class="catalogo-file">https://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/prod-1.pdf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Prod 2</td>
<td>G.1/2</td>
<td><a class="lsb-12 button-catalogo" href="#">Download</a></td>
<td class="catalogo-file">https://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/prod-2.pdf</td>
</tr>
...
```

And next I have JS to detect attachment link depending of clicked button, form data object and send it to back-end:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let targetButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.button-catalogo');  
    for (var i = 0; i < targetButtons.length; i++) {
            targetButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                let target = event.target;
                let targetTr = target.closest('tr');
                let targetCatalogoFile = targetTr.querySelector('.catalogo-file');
                let catalogoPath = targetCatalogoFile.innerHTML;
                openPopup(catalogoPath);
            });
     };
});
function openPopup(attachment) {
  const cf7Form = document.querySelector('form.wpcf7-form');
  if (cf7Form.length > 0) {   
      cf7Form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally

        // Get the form input values (name, last name, email)
        const name = cf7Form.querySelector('[name="your-name"]').value;
        const lastName = cf7Form.querySelector('[name="your-surname"]').value;
        const email = cf7Form.querySelector('[name="your-email"]').value;

        // Prepare the data to send to the backend
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('action', 'custom_send_email');
        formData.append('attachment', attachment);
        formData.append('name', name);
        formData.append('last_name', lastName);
        formData.append('email', email);

        // Send the form data using fetch
        fetch('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          // Handle the response (you can display a success message or perform other actions)
          //popup.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the popup after submitting
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error sending email:', error);
          // Handle the error (you can display an error message)
        });
      });    
  }
}
```

I found this solution in Internet and adopted it. And also solution contained this PHP to functions.php. It should work, but it doesn't.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_send_email', 'custom_send_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_send_email', 'custom_send_email');

function custom_send_email() {
  // Retrieve necessary data from POST input
  $attachment = sanitize_text_field($_POST['attachment']);

  // Configure email details
  $to = 'recipient@example.com';
  $subject = 'Email Subject';
  $message = 'Email Content';
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

  // Configure attachments based on the specified attachment
  $attachments = $attachment;

  // Send email with attachments
  wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);

  // Send a JSON response to the client
  wp_send_json_success('Email sent successfully.');
}
```

I see in Console error 400 when fetch tries to send data.
So can anybody say what wrong with this code? Or maybe this is wrong approach?